# Organizing a Coq proof

Tags: coq

What would be a more convenient better way to solve this proof in a less clustered/confusing way?

```
Lemma trial_ex : forall a b c d : Z, (a | b * c) -> Zis_gcd a b d -> (a | c * d).
Proof.
intros a b c d H1 H2.
destruct H1 as [z H3].
exists (d * z).
apply Zis_gcd_bezout in H2.
destruct H2 as [x y H4].
unfold Z.divide in *.
destruct H3 as [H5 H6].
rewrite <- H4.
rewrite Z.mul_add_distr_r.
rewrite H4.
replace (x * (a * z)) with (x * a * z) by ring.
replace (y * b * z) with (y * (b * z)) by ring.
replace (x * a * z + y * (b * z)) with (x * a * z + y * b * z) by ring.
replace (x * a * z + y * b * z) with ((x * a + y * b) * z) by ring.
replace (x * a + y * b) with d by assumption.
rewrite <- H4. 
rewrite <- Z.mul_add_distr_r.
rewrite Z.mul_comm with (n:=a) (m:=c). 
rewrite Z.mul_assoc. 
reflexivity.
```

Comment: Welcome to PA.SE! This is a good question. It is okay to set up multiple accounts, as long as you don't use them to vote oneself, circumvent bans, etc. I'm not an expert of Coq, but I hope someone else can answer your question!

Comment: Did you try to write a draft proof with pen and paper?  Your proof script did not compile on my computer (V 8.16). I don't think its OK to send snippets with errors. 
About readability: while  and after building a proof, using  bullets, tacticals, regrouping rewrites may help a lot.

Comment: A last comment about your proof.  The third line leads to a state where you would have to prove `d * c = d * (b * c)`.  I think you will have to take into account the mathematical intuition of this lemma, before translating its proof into Coq.

Comment: You should provide a MWE ([stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), so people can help you. 
Although the terms permit, I encourage you to register an account and build your reputation in the community. Even just asking interesting questions is a good way to build reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, in your tentative proof, you made a classic mistake: using the existential quantifier introduction tactic too early (i.e. without a sufficient context).

In the script below, I use `Zis_gcd_bezout`to get `u`and `v`, which are used in the argument of the `exists` tactic.

```
Require Import ZArith.
Open Scope Z_scope.
Require Import Znumtheory.

Lemma trial_ex : forall a b c d : Z, (a | b * c) -> Zis_gcd a b d -> (a | c * d).
Proof.
  intros a b c d H1 H2; destruct H1 as [z H3].
  apply Zis_gcd_bezout in H2; destruct H2 as [u v Huv].
  exists (c * u + v * z).  
  (* now easy to complete ...  *)
```

Comment: if only `eexists` would work here...